# Reshaping name and time data from (name within each time) to (all times for each name)

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to reshape a sign up sheet for an event using R.

Currently, each column represents a time period (ex: 9-11AM, 11AM-1PM, etc) and each row within each column is a contact email. Some contacts are only signed up for time periods, while others are signed up for multiple:

```
    9-11            11-1            1-3              3-5
xxx@email.com  zzz@email.com   zzz@email.com    xxx@email.com
yyy@email.com  yyy@email.com   yyy@email.com    yyy@email.com
```

I reshaped the data such that each email is paired with one time slot at at time:

```
xxx@email.com  "9-11"
yyy@email.com  "9-11"
zzz@email.com  "11-1"
yyy@email.com  "11-1"
zzz@email.com  "1-3"
yyy@email.com  "1-3"
xxx@email.com  "3-5"
yyy@email.com  "3-5"
```

In order to prepare for a mail merge to send out each assignment, I want to reshape the data such that each email observation is paired with all of the assignments to which they were scheduled (eg: one, two, three, or all) in a data.frame object:

```
xxx@email.com   "9-11" , "3-5
yyy@email.com   "9-11" , "11-1" , "1-3", "3-5"
zzz@email.com   "11-1" , "1-3"
```

My current code is:

```
assignments_final <- sapply(split(assignments[-1], assignments[1]), function(X) unname(unlist(X))) 
 # combine all time slots assigned to the same person into one list 

df <- data.frame()
 # create data frame to add each list object

for (i in 1:length(assignments_final)) {
  df <- rbind(df, assignments_final[[i]])
  }
# for each observation, add contact and all assignments to a new row
```

However, this code gives me an error: "In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "9-11") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated"

The data frame returned only contains whether or not each person is assigned to one of the shifts of the first person (eg: if the first person is assigned to shifts at 9-11 and 11-1, there are two columns; each column contains that shift if the person signed up for it or NA if they didn't.

How can I fix this issue such that there is either n different columns, one for each of the shifts with shifts for which that person isn't assigned are labelled as NA, OR all shifts are listed in one column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(V2~V1, data=df, FUN=paste0)
             V1                   V2
1 xxx@email.com            9-11, 3-5
2 yyy@email.com 9-11, 11-1, 1-3, 3-5
3 zzz@email.com            11-1, 1-3
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="xxx@email.com  9-11
yyy@email.com  9-11
                 zzz@email.com  11-1
                 yyy@email.com  11-1
                 zzz@email.com  1-3
                 yyy@email.com  1-3
                 xxx@email.com  3-5
                 yyy@email.com  3-5", header=FALSE)
```